# Issue updating an order with an authorized user(FastAPI)

Tags: fastapi, tortoise-orm

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I want to update an order with order id but I get `TypeError: dict() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)`. However, it worked fine when I updated a user.

```py
@order_router.put('/update/{order_id}', response_model=Order_Pydantic)
async def update_by_order_id(order_id: str, order=OrderModel, Authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    
    try:
        Authorize.jwt_required()
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORISED, detail='Invalid Token'
        )
    await Order.filter(id=order_id).update(**order.dict(exclude_unset=True))
    return Order_Pydantic.from_queryset_single(Order.get(id=order_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen where the error is coming from. I was using order=OrderModel instead of order: OrderModel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).